# How to render an image from an array in React?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am new to React. I just learned to create an api with nodejs and express from a MySQL. You can check out the json output api at [app.subarnanto.com/api/inventory](https://app.subarnanto.com/api/inventory).

How do you render the image? This is my code.
I also got a warning

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

And the third one, how do I improve my code? Thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Inventory extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inventory: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://app.subarnanto.com/api/inventory').then(res => {
      this.setState({ inventory: res.data });
      console.log({ inventory: res.data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.inventory.map(itemList => {
      let item = itemList;
      return (
        <div>
          <h4>Nama:  { item.name } </h4>
          <h4>Nomor Seri:  { item.serial } </h4>
          <h4>ID Tag:  { item.tag } </h4>
          <img src="{ item.image }"/>
        </div>
      );
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use inappropriate syntax for src attribute. You should remove quotes from src:
Also,  each child from the array should have a unique identifier key. In your case it's better to use: `<div key={ item.serial }>`

The working example:

```
render() {
    return this.state.inventory.map(item => {
        return (
            <div key={ item.serial }>
                <h4>Nama:  { item.name } </h4>
                <h4>Nomor Seri:  { item.serial } </h4>
                <h4>ID Tag: { item.tag } </h4>
                <img src={ item.image } />
            </div>
        );
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change image source from "{ item.image }" to src={ item.image } as string.

Code:

```
render() {
    return this.state.inventory.map((itemList, key) => {
      let item = itemList;
      return (
        <div key={key}>
          <h4>Nama:  { item.name } </h4>
          <h4>Nomor Seri:  { item.serial } </h4>
          <h4>ID Tag:  { item.tag } </h4>
          <img src={ item.image }/>
        </div>
      );
    })
  }
```

For warning - Each child in an array should have a unique "key" prop:

React uses the key prop to understand the component-to-DOM Element relation.

Comment: :) awesome.. you can mark it as correct if it works :D

Comment: I can't chose more than 1 answer but thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

To render the images just delete the double quotes from `img` tag.

The warning can be removed adding a `key` property to each element of the returned list. This way React can handle the minimal DOM change. There's more info in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys).

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Inventory extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            inventory: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://app.subarnanto.com/api/inventory').then(res => {
            this.setState({ inventory: res.data });
            console.log({ inventory: res.data });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.inventory.map(itemList => {
            let item = itemList;
            return (
                <div key={ item.id }>
                    <h4>Nama:  { item.name } </h4>
                    <h4>Nomor Seri:  { item.serial } </h4>
                    <h4>ID Tag:  { item.tag } </h4>
                    <img src={ item.image } />
                </div>
            );
        })
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a key for the dive tag.
Read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) in react docs.

> The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys:

React docs don't recommend indexes as keys more on it [here](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

```
export default class Inventory extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inventory: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://app.subarnanto.com/api/inventory').then(res => {
      this.setState({ inventory: res.data });
      console.log({ inventory: res.data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.inventory.map(itemList => {
      let item = itemList;
      return (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <h4>Nama:  { item.name } </h4>
          <h4>Nomor Seri:  { item.serial } </h4>
          <h4>ID Tag:  { item.tag } </h4>
          <img src={item.image}/>
        </div>
      );
    })
  }
}
```